# After ArgoCD role argocd user cant see helm parameters

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, cicd, argocd

I have a project in ArgoCD. Inside project I have an argocd application.
The application was deployed with helm.
I created role for the project which restricts access to particular application under this project for some users. The ArgoCD integrated with Keycloak with IDP google.
So it means user "A" have an full access to the application "A-dev" under project "A".
Everything seems fine but when the user logs in to the argocd it cant see the "helm parameters" in app details. But when I switch this user role to the ArgoCDAdmin it can see the helm parameters.
Do you have any idea why roles restricts to see "helm parameters" ?

Comment: Could you share the policy definitions in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in policy.
For getting helm values we should also give "repository, get" access to the policy.